# Run a Logon Script for User Group for Domain Server

Tags: windows, domain, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I've been searching for an hour and have not had any success so if I overlooked this as a previously answered question please let me know.

I am trying to have a logon script that maps drives on all computers in the domain.  I have followed this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781361(v=ws.10).aspx for adding the script.  However it still does not run for users on the domain when they log onto their computers.  Do I need to push it to the machines or activate it in some way?

To get into the Group Policy Editor I did the following (This might explain why its not working to someone).  I went into Group Policy Manager --> Forest --> Domains -->MyCompany.local --Default Domain Policy.  I right clicked on that and hit EDIT and from there I followed the instructions in the above link.  Then I went back to Group Policy Management and right clicked on Default Domain Policy and hit "Enforced".  Still nothing when users log in.

Any help is appreciated.  I am a developer not a sysadmin so active directory is out of my area of expertise.

I am using Windows 2012 Server Standard R2

I have also tried gpupdate /force

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I know exactly what you need to do to get a login script to run for all domain users at login. If you need help, I have an answer for you so let me know.

Comment: No I didn't get it to work.

Comment: Cade - Did you ever get around to this since I added the detail to help below.  I know even other methods to do this now too so let me know what's up when you get to it.

Answer (score 0):

### Setting up Logon Scripts to Map Drives at Logon

---

### 1. Create the Drive Mapping(s) Logon Script

**Note:** *This example uses "L" and "H" drive to map to UNC paths to server shares for those drive mappings but you can scale, adjust accordingly, etc. for your needs.*

```
IF EXIST L: NET USE L: /DELETE /YES
IF EXIST H: NET USE H: /DELETE /YES

NET USE L: \\<ServerName>\departments
NET USE H: \\<ServerName>\Homes\%username%

EXIT /B
```

---

### 2. Copy the Login Script to the Domain [Sysvol](https://blog.netwrix.com/2017/01/30/sysvol-directory/) Share

Go to `\\%logonserver%\sysvol` from a domain admin account once logged onto a machine. Once in there you will see a shortcut link with the domain name and you will want to click to go into it. Once in it you will see a folder named `scripts` and this is the folder the login script will reside.

> **Domain Name Folder Shortcut Link**
>
> - [image]
>
> **Scripts Folder**
>
> - [image]
>
> **Login Script**
>
> - [image]

---

### 3. Configure AD Account to use Logon Script

From **Active Directory Users and Computers** (logon to a domain controller), open the user account object which you want to map drives with a logon script. In the account's properties, go to the **Profile** tab and then in the **Logon script** field you type in just the file name of the batch file logon script name only that you dropped into the `\scripts` folder per the above step #2.

> [image]

---

### Final

Simply logoff any machines this account is already logged onto and then log back onto that machine for the drives to be mapped so if you're already logged onto a machine with that domain user account which you need the drive mapping(s), simply logoff of it and then log back onto it.